# How to set element full height in text-dependant div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an 'a' element fill the full height of the div, however I do not want it to take the full width.

It appears that my `display:block` is not helping me at all. Anyone know how to make this div full height? The height is variable, though. That's the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `display: inline-block;` instead of using `display: block;` because using `block` will take up 100% of width where `inline-block` won't, like this : [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s98US/)

Comment: Well your solution would work, if the height wouldn't be variable.. its more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/s98US/8/ (hope you can see it)

Comment: @SliQz If you said you need it 100% height than how can height be variable too?

Comment: If you'd take a look at my fiddle, you would see there are 2 span elements in my div. The first element, is supposed to be some random line of text. Right next to it, i need a link/div/spanthingy, wich has to follow the full height of this text.